# Find the distance of the point $( 1,2,3 )$ to ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

Find the distance of the point $( 1,2,3 )$ of the plane
                                                     $3x-2y+5z+17=0$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: from analytic formulas you know that the distance beteween a plane and a point is $$\frac{ax_0 + by_o+cz_o+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$ given a plane of equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$, like in this problem...

So substituting we get $$ d = \frac{3\cdot 1 -2\cdot 2 +5\cdot 3 +17}{\sqrt{3^2+(-2)^2+5^2}} = \frac{3-4+15+17}{\sqrt{9+4+25}}=\frac{31}{\sqrt{38}}$$

Comment: thanks , this is right , except that you forgot the root at the final answer .

Comment: ;) sorry, I've just seen the edit..

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  First, can you find the normal vector $\vec n$to the plane from the equation?  Now parameterize a line through $(1,2,3)$ and in the direction of the normal as $(1,2,3)+t\vec n$.  Find the parameter that represents the point on the line that is in the plane.